# Can a trait define construtor/initializer methods?

Tags: rust

A method defined by a trait can accept the implementing struct as a parameter via the `self` keyword. But I can't seem to figure out how to return an instance of the implementing struct. For example:

```
trait Construct {
    fn use_self(self) -> uint;
    fn make_self(n: uint) -> self;
}
```

`use_self` is fine and compiles, but `make_self` does not compile. Is there a way for a trait method to return an instance of the implementing struct, like a constructor or initializer?

Comment: Style note: the generic constructor is usually called `new`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way for a trait method to return an instance of the implementing struct, like a constructor or initializer?

Yes. Use `Self` as return type when declaring the trait method.